# Loading javascript file asynchronously

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

I am trying to make an asynchronous call to a server in the following way

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
    cache: true,
        async: true,
        dataType: "script",
        url:"www.xyz.com/yyy?host_name=abc.com&amp;size=S&amp;use_flash=YES&amp;use_transparent=YES&amp;lang=en",
       success: function(data) { 
            $("#verified").append(data);
                console.log("data is "+data);
                loading = false; 
            } 
       });
});
```

However the script is not being loaded asynchronously.What exactly am I missing? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You're missing `success` to retrieve response from the server!

Comment: Also, do you see the request happen in the Chrome/Firefox Inspector's Network panel? By the way, you shouldn't use HTML encodings for special characters ("&amp;") in javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [jQuery.getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) function.

Comment: yeah so much better than using plane javascript if you can afford it it has easier error handling for the uninitialized

Answer (score 3):

Use Following function for loading javascript asynchronous

```
 function script(url) {
        var scriptObject = document.createElement('script');
        scriptObject .type = 'text/javascript';
        scriptObject .async = true;
        scriptObject .src = url;
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scriptObject );            
    }
```

Comment: Hey thanks I already tried loading javascript file as you've suggested however it doesnot work as in my page takes a lot of time while loading script from the server and only after it loads other .js files are being loaded.Any idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

The "cache" and "async" properties for ajax call have the values "true" by default, you don't have to specify the defaults again.

You mentioned that it takes time for your file to load, that is probably because that the script file you are trying to load is of ample size. By ample size I mean more than 50 or 100 kb.

To reduce the time it takes for your file to load you can minify your js file which will help you reduce the file size of your script and eventually load faster on ajax call.

http://jscompress.com is one of the good on-line minifier available.

Alternatively, you can try using requirejs library which is widely used for loading script files asynchronously. You can download the requirejs library from the following link:
http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html